# Can't find Xcode 3 launch icon - Running both Xcode 3 and 4

Tags: xcode, launcher

At first, I installed Xcode 4 on my Lion machine, but since I couldn't find an easy way to implement tables, I also got Xcode 3 (place it in a separate folder: /Developer/Xcode 3). I can't find the Xcode 3 launcher anywhere... Anyone had this problem before?

Comment: What do you mean, "an easy way to implement tables"?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find your Xcode 3 IDE in `/Developer/xCode 3/Applications` (correct name is Xcode, by the way -- unlike "xCode 3", which is how you had it listed before Kevin's edit).

And you can drag the icon to your dock to add it there.  And then you'll have two Xcode icons in your dock.  Good luck telling one from the other.  ;-)

Comment: Oh, one thought I had about adding duplicate Xcode icons to the dock... you may be able to add a color to the icon (via the "Get Info" function) or possibly even copy / paste over another icon on top of it.